# inRange Query image output

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I've started learning opencv and have written the code below to obtain the output of an image (from input camera) in hsv and an inRange image ! 
the hsv output is fine but inRange o/p is just blank :| plz help am stumped

```
int main(int argc[], char** argv[])
   {
VideoCapture camera(CV_CAP_ANY);
Mat input;
Mat output(Size(input.size().height,input.size().width),input.type());
Mat img_thresh(Size(640,480),input.type());

namedWindow("input",0);
namedWindow("output",0);
namedWindow("threshold",0);

cv::Scalar hsv_min = cvScalar(0, 30, 80, 0);
    cv::Scalar hsv_max = cvScalar(20, 150, 255, 0);

for(;;)
{
    camera >> input;

    cvtColor(input,output,CV_BGR2HSV,1);
    cv::inRange(input,hsv_min,hsv_max,img_thresh);  

    imshow("input",input);
    imshow("output",output);
    imshow("threshold",img_thresh);

    cv::waitKey(40);    
}

return 0;
```

}

Comment: Your code working in my PC. Try  with different hsv_min and hsv_max values.

Comment: ok ty will try that :) oh and can u just post a screen shot :) of the inRange output ? !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You apply the inRange function to the input BGR image. You have to apply it to the HSV image, named output in your code. So the line should be :

```
cv::inRange(output,hsv_min,hsv_max,img_thresh);
```

Your code was working but you did not use the right image !

If you want to know HSV value in your image I suggest you to use :

```
cvSetMouseCallback("input", getObjectColor);
```

And :

```
void getObjectColor(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void *param = NULL) {

    // Vars
    CvScalar pixel;
    IplImage *hsv;

    if(event == CV_EVENT_LBUTTONUP) {

        // Get the hsv image
        hsv = cvCloneImage(image);
        cvCvtColor(image, hsv, CV_BGR2HSV);

        // Get the selected pixel
        pixel = cvGet2D(hsv, y, x);
        cvShowImage("getObjColor", hsv);
        // Change the value of the tracked color with the color of the selected pixel
        h = (int)pixel.val[0];
        s = (int)pixel.val[1];
        v = (int)pixel.val[2];
        cout << "Color HSV = h:" << pixel.val[0] << " | s:" << pixel.val[1] << " | v:" << pixel.val[2] << endl;

        // Release the memory of the hsv image
            cvReleaseImage(&hsv);
    } 
}
```

You will need to create some variables to make this work, the code was taken from the internet (can't remember where !)